# How can I remove an image in a custom folder in cloudinary by nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I tried to remove an imagine on cloudinary and sucessfully following sample code of cloudinary APIs docs. But when I uploaded an image to a folder and tried to delete it after, I can't delete this.

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy('sample', 
  function(error, result) {console.log(result, error) });
```

or

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy('sample', { folder: "my_folder/" }, 
  function(error, result) {console.log(result, error) });
```

The response is always: `{ result: 'not found' }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(uploadResult.public_id, (error, result) => {
      console.log(result); // { result: 'ok' }
});
```

I figured out that the .detroy() api works well with public_id field you received when you upload your image to cloudinary, not a plain text which defines your path to the image.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: You are right. We don't need to another parameter, just public_id to delete image. My bad in code, thank you very much <3

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late, but it may help others :)

The `public_id` changes depending on the folders the file is located in.

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(
  'folder/sample', 
  function(error, result) {
    console.log(result, error)
  }
);
```